# How do I bind a checkbox to a select disabled property using ngx data binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, web-component

I am building an angular 6 app and I would like to bind a show/hide logic of a `select` to a checkbox `input`. I am not sure where is my problem. I guess I would need an observable, but I wonder whether there is a way to do it directly (directly as without using a variable in my typescript code).

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<label><input #bl id="checkBox" type="checkbox"> ere</label>
      <br/>
      <span>{{bl.checked}}</span>
      <br/>
      <select id="bl_select" class="select" *ngIf="(bl.checked)">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">Else</option>
      </select>`,
  styles: []
})
export class HelloComponent  {
}
```

You can find a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1aq65u).

Related to [How do I bind a checkbox to a select disabled property using angular data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716081/how-do-i-bind-a-checkbox-to-a-select-disabled-property-using-angular-data-bindin) but with ngx.

This was a common use of data-binding back in my wpf days :)

Comment: See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4639e).

Comment: @ConnorsFan it is working, but not directly. We are relying on an external variable. Is it possible to bind directly?

Comment: I don't think so. As you see in your stackblitz, change detection is not performed without Angular data binding or event binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do what you want (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3bwgkd)):

```
<input #bb type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="bb.checked">
<select class="select" [hidden]="!bb.checked">
```

It also works with an ad hoc property added to the input element (e.g. `showSelect`). As long as data binding is set on the check box, the view will be updated (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-necjy4)).

```
<input #bb type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="bb.showSelect">
<select class="select" [hidden]="!bb.checked">
```

---

That being said, binding to a model defined in the component class is more in line with the Angular way of doing things:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showSelect">
<select class="select" [hidden]="!showSelect">
```

```
export class HelloComponent {
  showSelect= false;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Got it! (yes I use reactive or template form at work)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe over-did a bit,

```
export class HelloComponent {
    public flag = false;
}
```

If you defined this variable in your component, then in your template you can just do

```
<select *ngIf="flag">
```

Comment: Can you share a demo? I just try it and it doesnt work. Naybe I missed something.

Comment: @windmaomao - You should add `[(ngModel)]="flag"` to the checkbox element.

Comment: @ConnorsFan does not work either. Can you share a working demo?

Comment: @windmaomao - Yes, but how is `flag` modified?

Comment: flag will be automatically updated if you change it dynamically, for instance you have a button, and when you click, it'll set `this.flag=true`

Comment: @windmaomao - He wants to show/hide the `select` element depending on the status of the checkbox. That's why I suggested to bind `flag` to the checkbox.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, oh i see. if that's the case. Yeah maybe you are right. I wouldn't do that anyway, because you might run into some `chicken/egg ` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I *quite* found it. [Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikc7hf):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<label><input #bb type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="this.flag">Show select</label>
      <span>({{this.flag}})</span>
      <select class="select" [hidden]="!this.flag">
        <option value="0">All</option>
        <option value="1">Else</option>
      </select>`,
  styles: []
})
export class HelloComponent  {
}
```

By the way, if you are wondering what is the difference between `ngIf*` and `[hidden]`. When the expression is falsy:

- `*ngIf` removes the element from the DOM.
- `[hidden]` hide the element from the user.

Edit: As @ConnorsFan said this is quite the same solution as the one discussed by @windmaomao and himself. `this.flag` will create the `flag` property.

Comment: This is the same solution that I showed in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4639e). Your code actually creates an undeclared `checked` flag in the component class. You can see it by removing the `flag` declaration in my code; the code still works with `[(ngModel)]="flag"`. In other words, `this.checked` in your code does not refer to the `checked` property of the checkbox element but to a property of the component class.